# Random walk algorithm for pricing barrier options

Tags: algorithm, matlab, random, barrier

How to realize the random walk algorithm with MATLAB? I don't understand this algorithm, because the condition 3 never holds. I post my code in the end.

> Choose a time-step `h>0` so that `M=9/h` is a integer.
>       Set `log(L_0) = L_0 = 0.13` and `Z(0)=0`.
>       `rho_k` are independent random variables distributed by the law `P(+-1)=0.5`
>
> ```
> 1) log(L_{k+1}) = log(L_k)-0.5*sigma^2*h+sigma*sqrt(h)*rho_{k+1}
>
> 2) Z_{k+1} = Z_k - sigma* [(erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log((25*exp(log L_k))/7) + 9/32))/3)/2 - erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log(100*exp(log L_k)) + 9/32))/3)/2 + erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log(7/(25*exp(log L_k))) - 9/32))/3)/56 - erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log(196/(25*exp(log L_k))) - 9/32))/3)/56 + (exp(log L_k)*((2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(7/(25*exp(log L_k))) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2)) - (2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(196/(25*exp(log L_k))) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2))))/28 - exp(log L_k)*((2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log((25*exp(log L_k))/7) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2)) - (2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(100*exp(log L_k)) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2))) - (14*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(7/(25*exp(log L_k))) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(75*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2)) + (14*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(196/(25*exp(log L_k))) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(75*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2)) + (2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log((25*exp(log L_k))/7) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(150*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2)) - (2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(100*exp(log L_k)) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(150*exp(log L_k)*pi^(1/2))))]*sqrt(h)*rho_{k+1};
>
> 3) log L_k < log(H)+1/2*sigma^2*h-sigma*sqrt(h)
> ```
>
> ```
> H=0.28
> sigma=0.25
> K=0.01
> ```

To realize the algorithm we follow the random walk generated by (1),
and at each time `t_k`; we check whether the condition 3 holds. If it does not, `L_k` has reached the boundary zone and we stop the chain at `log(H)`. If it does,
we perform (1)-(2) to find `log(L_k+1)` and `Z_{k+1}`. `If k+1=M;` we stop, otherwise we continue with the algorithm.

The outcome of simulating each trajectory is a point `(t_kappa, log(L_kappa), Z_kappa)`.

Evaluate the expectation `E[(exp(log(L_{kappa}))-K)^+ * Chi(kappa=M) + Z_{kappa}]=price` with the Monte Carlo technique and do `10^6` Monte Carlo runs.

Here is my code. It doesn't work, because I don't get something near `0.0657` (the result).

```
Y = zeros(1,M+1); %ln L_k = Y(k)
Z = zeros(1,M+1);
sigma = 0.25;
H = 0.28;
K = 0.01;
Y(1) = 0.13; 
Z(1) = 0;
M = 90;
h = 0.1;

for k = 1:M+1
    vec = [-1 1];
    index = random('unid', length(vec),1);
    x(1,k) = vec(index);
end %'Rho' 

for k = 1:M
    if Y(k) < log(H) + 1/2*sigma^2*h - sigma*sqrt(h) %Bedingung
       Y(k+1) = Y(k) - (1/2)*(sigma)^2*h + sigma*sqrt(h)*x(k+1);
       Z(k+1) = Z(k) + (-sigma*(erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log((25*exp(Y(k)))/7) + 9/32))/3)/2 - erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log(100*exp(Y(k))) + 9/32))/3)/2 + erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log(7/(25*exp(Y(k)))) - 9/32))/3)/56 - erfc((2*2^(1/2)*(log(196/(25*exp(Y(k)))) - 9/32))/3)/56 + (exp(Y(k))*((2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(7/(25*exp(Y(k)))) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2)) - (2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(196/(25*exp(Y(k)))) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2))))/28 - exp(Y(k))*((2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log((25*exp(Y(k)))/7) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2)) - (2*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(100*exp(Y(k))) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(3*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2))) - (14*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(7/(25*exp(Y(k)))) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(75*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2)) + (14*2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(196/(25*exp(Y(k)))) + 9/32)^2)/9))/(75*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2)) + (2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log((25*exp(Y(k)))/7) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(150*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2)) - (2^(1/2)*exp(-(8*(log(100*exp(Y(k))) - 9/32)^2)/9))/(150*exp(Y(k))*pi^(1/2))))*sqrt(h)*x(k+1);          
    else
        Y(k)=log(H);            
        break
    end       
end

if k == M    
end

if (L(M)-K) > 0
   (L(M)-K);
else
   0;
end

return
exp(Y(M))-K+Z(M)
```